# FirebaseListAdapter not showing database results android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am making a chat app on Android that uses google firebase to store messages that users write to each other. To display these messages to the users I read them from the database and organize them into a custom `ListView` with a `ListAdapter`.

I'm using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.3`

the problem is that the list view is always empty, the `FirebaseListAdapter` is not showing database results

[image: Database image]

```
private void displayChatMessages() {

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.community_message)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class ChatMessage {

    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;

        // Initialize to current time
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like someone already asked this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271185/display-firebase-database-content-in-a-firebaselistadapter). Please don't post the same question twice. Just wait for it to be solved.

Comment: not my question .. same code because it is a demo on the internet

Comment: I understand... How are your Firebase Database rules set?

Comment: what is "Firebase Database rules" mean?
do you mean this
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: Exactly. Are you using Firebase Authentication in your project?

Comment: yes and it work fine . i can push record and it saved in database correctly.i trace the code and find it never firing `code`populateView() method .. i thing this is the problem but can't find any solution

Comment: Can you post your ChatMessage class?

Comment: i edited the question and added the chatmessage.class